# My "viewDidLoad" is in a loop

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, storyboard

I created a new iPad app using XCode4 and Storyboard.  I have several (5) various view controllers.  I created a class (HomeViewClass), and took one of the view controllers and and changed the class to "HomeViewClass", and put this code in the viewDidLoad method.  I originally had this in a non-storyboard project, where it worked perfectly...  (it's looping where indicated).

```
allButtons = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int k = 40, m = 0; m < 6; m++, k+= 42)   //  this controls the vertical distance between rows
    for(int i = 0, j=182; i < 7; i++, j+=82) {  //  this controls the size (j) and horizontal distance
        calendarButton *cb= [calendarButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [cb makeFrame:CGRectMake(j, k, 80, 40) number: allButtons.count+1 color:[UIColor orangeColor]];
        //                       x  y   w   h
        [self.view addSubview:cb];  //  <------------------- causing a viewDidLoad loop
        [allButtons addObject:cb];  // put it in the array
    }
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You should cache self.view in a local variable and check that you called [super viewDidLoad] at the beginning of your method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *rootView = self.view;

    for(int k = 40, m = 0; m < 6; m++, k+= 42) {
        for(int i = 0, j=182; i < 7; i++, j+=82) {
            UIButton *cb = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

            [rootView addSubview:cb];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did a "clean" and now it's working again... let's hear it for XCode!

Answer (score 1):

Did a Project -> Clean and it's now working.

Comment: choose more descriptive variable names... what is this i, j, k, m ? :) for example > http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php I Wish you luck with your app :)

Answer (score 1):

What fixed it for me was removing the loadView function.